# Publish Android aar to artifactory

Tags: android, android-library, artifactory

I'm stuck with integrating artifactory 3.0.1 plugin with Gradle. I'm using Android Studio 1.0 so I'm guessing that I'm on Gradle 2.0. Any examples on publishing to artifactory using the 3.0.1 plugin would be highly helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [A private Maven repository for Android in 30 min](https://jeroenmols.com/blog/2015/08/06/artifactory/) Tried with latest Android Studio 3.3, worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

Publishing to Artifactory is just a configuration task. You just need to configure two plugins, `com.jfrog.artifactory` and `maven-publish`, and run `artifactoryPublish` Gradle's task. But... let's explain it by code, to ease copypasting :·)

At your library's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        aar(MavenPublication) {
            groupId 'com.fewlaps.something' //put here your groupId
            artifactId 'productname' //put here your artifactId
            version '7.42.0' //put here your library version

            // Tell maven to prepare the generated "*.aar" file for publishing
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.getName()}-release.aar")
        }
    }
}

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'https://your-artifactory-host.com/artifactory'
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = "libs-release-local"
            username = "username"
            password = "password"
        }
        defaults {
            // Tell the Artifactory Plugin which artifacts should be published to Artifactory.
            publications('aar')
        }
    }
}
```

And then, run `./gradlew artifactoryPublish`

In addition, if you want to upload the artifact everytime you push a tag to GitHub, add this code to your `.travis.yml`

```
deploy:
  - provider: script
    script: ./gradlew artifactoryPublish
    skip_cleanup: true
    on:
      tags: true
```

If it doesn't launch a build for the tag when you push a tag to GitHub, check that you're building `vX.X.X` tags on Travis:

```
# Build only master and "vX.X.X" tags to prevent flooding Travis machines
branches:
  only:
    - master
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

Comment: Since Android Gradle plugin version 3.6, you can configure a Maven publication simply with `from components.release`. Outside of that, this answer remains accurate. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/maven-publish-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

JFrog publishes a fully functional example of publishing aar to Artifactory. [Here you go](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-examples). Select the version of plugin you work with and look for aar example.

Comment: Yes I've tried it and it works great for the old plugin (2.3) but not the 3.0.1

Comment: We'll take a look and report.

Comment: I managed to configure the plugin and now the publishing seems to work. However I'm unable to resolve the published artifact through gradle.  maven {
        url "http://localhost:8081/artifactory/gradle"
        credentials
                {
                    username = 'admin'
                    password = 'password'
                }
    } . any idea ?

Comment: You need to manage the resolve through the Artifactory plugin:
artifactory{
.
.
.
resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-release' 
            username = artifactory_user
            password = artifactory_password
        }
    }
}

Comment: Isn't it possible to resolve without the artifactory plugin ?. As a gradle compile dependency ?

Comment: I resorted in using Apache Archiva instead

Comment: Here go custom DSL, CI server integration and tons of other features.

Comment: Yup, I can't get the gradle artifactory plugin to work with an android library either.

Example at https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/gradle-android-aar is now outdated a few versions behind the latest android gradle plugin.

Comment: Link in the answer results in 404 (page not found) error.